# jQuery getJSON output nothing

Tags: json, jquery

I try to display JSON data in html file with jQuery.

**But in html I have nothing for output even *`null`* or *`unindefied`***

I try with external JSON data from Flickr and I see at least `[Object]`

Also I try to test both files - HTML and JSON on local server - again nothing

I add MIME Type on my server for application/json

I checked JSON- it's valid

In Firebug I see JSON Response (see image below)

On same page I use and jQuery mobile and DW Fluid grid layout if it matters.

**my JSON is generated with PHP json_encode:**

```
({ "title": "Art and Culture",
"items": [
{"id":"kunst-im-tunnel","lat":"51.219917"},
{"id":"kunsthalle","lat":"51.227568"},
{"id":"kunstsammlung-nordrhein-westfalen","lat":"51.22841"}]
})
```

**PHP code for JSON**

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); 
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$out = json_encode($post);
echo "({ \"title\": \"Art and Culture\",\"items\": " .$out." })";
?>
```

**my javascript code is:**

```
$.getJSON("http://example.com/app.php?cat=category&jsoncallback=?",
{format: "json"},
function(data){
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){

        $('<li>' +  item.id + '</li>').appendTo("#list");

    });

});
```

Screenshot from Firebug:
[image: Firebug Net result]

Comment: can you show your HTML or create a fiddle?

Comment: [link](http://app.duesseldorf24.eu/category-art.html) complete code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
({ "title": "Art and Culture",
"items": [
{"id":"kunst-im-tunnel","lat":"51.219917"},
{"id":"kunsthalle","lat":"51.227568"},
{"id":"kunstsammlung-nordrhein-westfalen","lat":"51.22841"}]
})
```

**IS NOT VALID JSON.**

But this one is Valid JSON

```
 { "title": "Art and Culture",
   "items": [
              {"id":"kunst-im-tunnel","lat":"51.219917"},
              {"id":"kunsthalle","lat":"51.227568"},
              {"id":"kunstsammlung-nordrhein-westfalen","lat":"51.22841"}]
 }
```

And it will work nicely. Here is the working sample http://jsfiddle.net/cqfQp/1/

Use [jsonlint](http://www.jsonlint.com) to validate JSON.

Another suggestion is, Try to avoid calling the `append` function in a loop. Create a variable and call the function only once. Something like this

```
     var strItems="";
     $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
         strItems+='<li>' +  item.id + '</li>';
     });
     $("#list").html(strItems);
```

**EDIT :**  Make sure you call the getJSON on document [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function

```
 $(function(){
      $.getJSON("http://example.com/app.php?cat=category&jsoncallback=?",function(data){
        var strItems="";
        $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            strItems+='<li>' +  item.id + '</li>';
        });
        $("#list").html(strItems);    
     });
 });
```

Comment: [json output](http://app.duesseldorf24.eu/app.php?cat=art-and-culture|art) I fixed JSON code it but not works again

Comment: @awenart : It works for me. Make sure you call that in the ready event. http://jsfiddle.net/8EY7B/3/

Comment: @awenart: Are you making a cross domain request ?

Comment: Yes I try it but not works.
Both html and json are in the same domain

Comment: [html with my json](http://app.duesseldorf24.eu/category-art.html)
[html with Flickr json](http://app.duesseldorf24.eu/category-art2.html) - I see at least undefined

Comment: I guess you should wrap the JSON with callback function name to use jsonp requests

Answer (score 0):

You are generating invalid JSON — the parentheses enclosing your entire JSON expression should not be there.

Comment: I try every variant with JSON formating but this not change anything